# react native bottom sheet and tab bar

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

I want to implement a player bar in my custom tab bar like apple music or spotify does.
For TabNavigator I have:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LibraryStack,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'HomeStack',
  tabBarComponent: props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />,
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
  }
});
```

And for my custom TabBar I wanted something like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation';
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet'

const CustomTabBar = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <BottomSheet
         snapPoints = {[450, 300, 0]}
         renderContent = {this.renderInner}
         renderHeader = {this.renderHeader}
       />
      <BottomTabBar {...props} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CustomTabBar;
```

Problem is: the BottomSheet is behind the TabBar and blocks touches on the tabbar, so I cannot switch between tabs anymore. How to deal with this problem?

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you move it in front with `zIndex`?

Comment: Can you post the project by expo snack?

Comment: I found the solution, I had to wrap the BottomTabBar in a View with zIndex of 110 (has to be more than 100)